# Copy/paste filtered cells vba

Tags: excel, vba

Column B contains the numbers 17, 1408 and some numbers that have this format 000000-000-00

I put a filter for cells that contain "-". It shows me the numbers with the format above.

I want to copy them to column A, but every one of them to be on the same row.

If I select then copy/paste it will tell me that it cannot do this with multiple selections.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Private Sub CopyRange()

    Dim r1 As Range
    Dim r2 As Range

    Set r1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C1,A3:C3")
    Set r2 = ActiveSheet.Range("D5")

    r1.Copy r2

End Sub
```

As a side note, you can use `advanced filter` in the code or in excel and specify a range for it to be copied to.

Answer (score 1):

In  A2:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("-",B2)),"",B2)
```

Fill down the formula in Col A.  Follow up with copy/pastespecial-values if you need to convert from a formula to a fixed value.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a new column.
2. In your new column, enter this formula and fill down for your entire dataset:

   `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-",B1)),"Match","")`
3. Sort the table using your new column. Then you can copy & paste.